# Android webview recaptcha challenge

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading an auth webpage in an android view that is protected by recaptcha, the problem is that the challenge (choosing a set of images) is displayed all the time for the end-user.

I've tested this with a bunch of devices and different users.

Is there a configuration to that I need to do on my webview that will prevent the challenge being displayed all the time?